# Postgis - Error when loading a dbf file

Tags: postgresql, postgis, dbf

I'm importing .dbf files to my database, i had no trouble uploading  other files but i think this one may be a corrupt file although it seems unlikely, i uploaded the file on Qgis to check the data and the file, and looks fine.
I'm using the postgis shapefile and dbf loader.

How i can upload/fix the file? i tried to save it again with Qgis but it throws the same error.

The error thrown:

> Importing with configuration: 01, public, geom,
>   C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\01.dbf, mode=c, dump=0, simple=0,
>   geography=0, index=0, shape=1, srid=0
>   C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\01.dbf: shape (.shp) or index files
>   (.shx) can not be opened, will just import attribute data.
>
> Failed in
>   pgui_exec(): ERROR:  un identificador delimitado tiene largo cero en o
>   cerca de «""» LINE 203: "" varchar(254),
>             ^
>
> Shapefile import failed.

EDIT: I took a better look on the data, the problem was the table had several null columns with null data, i just deleted them and I uploaded into my database without problems.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes i did it,  i get the same error

Comment: Sound very weird, try creating a select with only the ID and the geom, maybe is a field with bad data type. Then save that result as shape and try loading again

Comment: Told you the problem was the fields ;)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: One of you should create an answer.  Every question should have an answer.  ;)